# Regex in Linq statement?

Tags: c#, regex, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm writing a short C# to parse a given XML file. But 1 of the tag values can change, but always includes words "Fast Start up" (disregarding case and spaces, but needs to be in the same order) in the where clause. I'm not sure how I would do this in a sql like statement in C#.

```
var selected = from cli in doc.Descendants(xmlns+ "Result")
     where cli.Element(xmlns + "ResultsLocation").Value == "Assessments-Fast-Startup"
                       select cli;
```

Comment: where is the sql? - all i see is linq to xml

Comment: are you looking for the exact string, or something like: fast*startup

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for the exact string - can you just use a `String.Contains` ?

```
var selected = from cli in doc.Descendants(xmlns+ "Result")
     where cli.Element(xmlns + "ResultsLocation").Value.Contains("Assessments-Fast-Startup")
     select cli;
```

Otherwise, something like:

```
var rx = new Regex("fast(.*?)startup", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var selected = from cli in doc.Descendants(xmlns+ "Result")
    where rx.IsMatch(cli.Element(xmlns + "ResultsLocation").Value)
    select cli;
```

Comment: Nah, that's just saying "fast{anything}startup". You can disregard case in the regex definition

Answer (score 2):

a regex of `fast[- ]?start[- ]?up` should work

where an optional *dash* or *space* could be separating the word parts

```
...
where Regex.IsMatch(
    cli.Element(xmlns + "ResultsLocation").Value, 
    "fast[- ]?start[- ]?up", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
)
select cli
```

if you find you need to tweak the regex try a regex tester like http://regexpal.com/

As @DaveBish has mentioned you might be fine with `.Contains(...)` test instead of a regex or even `.ToLower().Contains(...)` chaining (you may also need a `null` check as well)